# How to deal with no value after a filter

Tags: vba, excel

This is my data base:
[image: This is my data base]

Now, this is my sheet "product":

[image]

And this si my sheet "article":

[image]

I have this piece of code that actualy works:

```
    ' Extract Products
    ReDim Preserve aProducts(2 * .Rows.Count)
    lRow = 1
    sCriteria = "Produit"
    aProducts(lRow) = Array("Id Product", "Value A", "Value B", "Value C")
    aHdr = Array("Id product", "Value A", "Value B", "Value C", _
        "Type of value A", "Type of value B", "Type of Value C")
    GoSub Get_Field_Post

    ' Extract Products - Value A
    b = aPos(5)
    .AutoFilter Field:=b, Criteria1:=sCriteria
    For Each vItm In .Offset(1, 0).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count) _
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
        With vItm
            lRow = 1 + lRow
            aProducts(lRow) = Array(.Cells(aPos(1)).Value2, _
                .Cells(aPos(2)).Value2, Empty, Empty)
        End With
    Next
    .AutoFilter Field:=b
```

The entire code is a bit longer, that's why I added a file, feel free to download it to understand the entire code.

It works perfectly except when there is an entire (except the title) empty column like this:

[image]

Some help would be apreciated.

Link to download the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DpGwPWsIfbUjlueHBjTU50Mzg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could go like this (see commented line):

```
.AutoFilter Field:=b, Criteria1:=sCriteria
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| check if any cell filtered other than header
    For Each vItm In .Offset(1, 0).Resize(-1 + .Rows.COUNT) _
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
        With vItm
            lRow = 1 + lRow
            aProducts(lRow) = Array(.Cells(aPos(1)).Value2, _
                .Cells(aPos(2)).Value2, Empty, Empty)
        End With
    Next
End If
```

Comment: thank you for your time, but I don't understand this piece of code... :/ do I have to add it on every loop?

Comment: Wrap every loop that relies on `Autofilter()` result inside a `If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then ... End If` block.

Comment: alright, I did it, it seems to work, I'll check values, but I don't understand why it's "ignoring" the column when there are no data found

Comment: Fine. While I don't get what "ignoring" you are not understanding. Finally, since my answer solved your question (_"How to deal with no value after a filter"_) you may want to mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: yep, I just ckeck my values and it seems to work very well, thanks a lot and thank you for your time =) have a great day/evening

Comment: Thank you! ^^ I'll need luck and lot of cofee ahah!